# how to generate monthly days with PHP?

Tags: php

Im trying to generate days of the current month like this

```
    $year = date('Y');
    $month = date('m');

    $dayCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
    {
        $tree_data->data[$i] = $year."-".$month."-".$i;
    }
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($tree_data);
```

which gives me output like

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2011-12-1
            [2] => 2011-12-2
            [3] => 2011-12-3
            [4] => 2011-12-4
            [5] => 2011-12-5
            [6] => 2011-12-6
            [7] => 2011-12-7
            [8] => 2011-12-8
            [9] => 2011-12-9
            [10] => 2011-12-10
            [11] => 2011-12-11
            [12] => 2011-12-12
            [13] => 2011-12-13
            [14] => 2011-12-14
            [15] => 2011-12-15
            [16] => 2011-12-16
            [17] => 2011-12-17
            [18] => 2011-12-18
            [19] => 2011-12-19
            [20] => 2011-12-20
            [21] => 2011-12-21
            [22] => 2011-12-22
            [23] => 2011-12-23
            [24] => 2011-12-24
            [25] => 2011-12-25
            [26] => 2011-12-26
            [27] => 2011-12-27
            [28] => 2011-12-28
            [29] => 2011-12-29
            [30] => 2011-12-30
            [31] => 2011-12-31
        )

)
```

my problem is i want to get 1 - 9 days like

```
2011-12-01, 2011-12-02 etc...
```

any idea how to get the output like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `sprintf`.

```
sprintf('%1$02d', $i);
```

---

A different approach could be to use the `DateTime` object:

```
$aDates = array();
$oStart = new DateTime('2011-12-01');
$oEnd = clone $oStart;
$oEnd->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));

while($oStart->getTimestamp() < $oEnd->getTimestamp()) {
  $aDates[] = $oStart->format('Y-m-d');
  $oStart->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should be sufficient. :)

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$dayCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
{
    $tree_data->data[$i] = $year."-".$month."-".str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
$ret = implode(", ", $tree_data->data);
```

Comment: Edited, that was indeed a mistake on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Check out str_pad().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

$dayCount = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,$month,$year);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
{
    $tree_data->data[$i] = $year."-".$month."-".(($i < 10)?'0'.$i:$i);
}
print "<pre>";
print_r($tree_data);
```

Comment: Not sure about the ternary. Aren't you just reinventing wheels? Why not use str_pad?

Answer (score 1):

Well as other answers suggest you can add `0` to the day conditionally, or here is another way to go about the things just in case.

```
    $startMonth = date('Y-m-01');
    $endMonth = date('Y-m-t');
    $i = 0;
    while(strtotime($startMonth) <= strtotime($endMonth)){
       $tree_date->date[$i] = $startMonth;
       $startMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startMonth.' +1 days'));
       $i++;
    }

   print_r($tree_date);
```

Comment: Or possibly rather than $endMonth = date('Y-m-00', strtotime('+1 month')); you could use $endMonth = date('Y-m-t');