# With php, populate an array of days in current month

Tags: php, calendar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to generate monthly days with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616197/how-to-generate-monthly-days-with-php)

With PHP, given a month in this format: 10 - October, 11 - November, how would I populate an array where the keys represent each day for the given month.

So,

e.g for February you'd have an array with keys 1-28.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this function:

```php
function dates_month($month, $year) {
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $dates_month = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
        $mktime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year);
        $date = date("d-M-Y", $mktime);
        $dates_month[$i] = $date;
    }

    return $dates_month;
}

echo"<pre>"; 
print_r(dates_month(2, 2012));
echo"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = '02 February';
$days = array_fill_keys(
    range(1, date('t', gmmktime(0, 0, 0, (integer) $date, 1))),
    NULL
);
```

Assumption, for this year (else February could be 28 or 29)

Answer (score 1):

**[cal_days_in_month](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)** — Return the number of days in a month for a given year and calendar

```
int cal_days_in_month ( int $calendar , int $month , int $year )
```

**eg**.

```
$date = '02 February';
list($month, $monthname) = split(' ', $date);
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, intval($month), 2012); //$num = 29
```

Fill up an array with the right number, from `$num`.