# Pivot query to display data for each day of the year

Tags: php, mysql

I have one database table as following:

```
id|start_date|end_date|sec
1|2018-08-01|2018-08-03|2500
2|2018-08-02|2018-08-13|100
3|2018-08-01|2018-08-05|500
```

So I want to display the report date wise so that user can know how many seconds available in specific days.

For example, I need below things:

```
Date /Day            total
2018-08-01  (2500+500)=3000     //this date comes in 1&3 records
2018-08-02  (2500+100+500)=3100 //this date comes in all 1,2,&3 records
2018-08-03  (2500+100+500)=3100 //this date comes in all 1,2,&3 records
2018-08-04  (100+500)=600       //this date comes in 2&3 records
2018-08-05  (100+500)=600       //this date comes in 2&3 records
2018-08-06  (100)=100           //this date comes in 3  records
```

I am trying to use mysql and php but I don't know how to do.

Comment: What are the "specific days" exactly ? Are they also fetched from DB ? Or are they days from current month ? Or something else ?

Comment: you can consider whole year days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean way to generate a table with each day of current year on the fly, I took the subtable code from [generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range) (to give him credit) because it didn't use any loops etc and had a short execution time. That being said, you can go with :

```
SELECT
dpy.day as Day,
SUM(IFNULL(t.sec,0)) as total
FROM
(
select a.Date as day
from (
    select DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-12-31') - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY as Date
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
) a
where a.Date between DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-01-01') and DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE(), '%Y-12-31')
) dayPerYear dpy
LEFT JOIN
your_table t ON dpy.day > t.start_date AND dpy.day < t.end_date
GROUP BY dpy.day
```

Just replace `your_table` by your table name

Comment: What do you mean by 'clean'? This seems fairly straightforward !?! Although, given that the OP mentions PHP, the above seems like it may be unnecessary.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I just meant visually. I understood OP's post as he was trying to use php to do so because he lacked a pure sql solution. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @Aurelien thanks for your answer! It's only giving results upto 2018-08-09 date not the end of the day i.e. 2018-12-31

Comment: @Aurelien I think it's get only upto today's date. I need the day for whole year.

Comment: @Pratik Yes, sorry, there was something left in the subtable code that I didn't adapt. I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets begin by assuming that your records are already fetched and are available in an associative array named $rows (after a query and a mysqli_fetch_array type call):

```
$ra=array();
$nr=count($rows);    
for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) {
   $start=$rows['start_date'];
   $end=$rows['end_date'];
   $sec=$rows['sec'];
   if (isset($ra[$start])) {
      $ra[$start]+=$sec;
   } else {
      $ra[$start]=$sec;
   }
   if (isset($ra[$end])) {
      $ra[$end]+=$sec;
   } else {
      $ra[$end]=$sec;
   }
}
print_r($ra);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through days

```
select sum(sec) from table where ('2018-08-01') between start_date and end_date ;
```

For generating the days [With php, populate an array of days in current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118694/with-php-populate-an-array-of-days-in-current-month?noredirect=1&lq=1)